# c7000 - 1GB Ethernet Pass-Thru

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, blade-server

[image]I cant get the BL460c Gen 8 to work with the 1GB Ethernet Pass-Thru non of the ports are mapped or lighting up.

[image]

Comment: Do you have a cable in the port on the passthrough module?

Comment: yes but none of the lights are on

Answer (score 1):

The blade server's NICs are hardwired to interconnect bays 1 and 2 on a C7000.

For your system, NIC1 in the blade will map to port 1 on the single passthrough module you have.

[image]